# Why set the stop flag using `memory_order_seq_cst`, if you check it with `memory_order_relaxed`?

Tags: c++, concurrency, stdatomic

Herb Sutter, in his "atomic<> weapons" talk, shows several example uses of atomics, and one of them boils down to following: ([video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeLBd2EJLOU&t=4507s), timestamped)

- A main thread launches several worker threads.
- Workers check the stop flag:

  ```cpp
  while (!stop.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
  {
      // Do stuff.
  }
  ```
- The main thread eventually does `stop = true;` (note, using order=`seq_cst`), then joins the workers.

Sutter explains that checking the flag with order=`relaxed` is ok, because who cares if the thread stops with a slightly bigger delay.

But why does `stop = true;` in the main thread use `seq_cst`? The slide says that it's purposefully not `relaxed`, but doesn't explain *why*.

It looks like it would work, possibly with a larger stopping delay.

Is it a compromise between performance and how fast other threads see the flag? I.e. since the main thread only sets the flag once, we might as well use the strongest ordering, to get the message across as quickly as possible?

Comment: Related to the part if stronger order for `stop = true` will make the thread stop slower or faster -- [Does hardware memory barrier make visibility of atomic operations faster in addition to providing necessary guarantees?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61591287/2945027)

Comment: To me it looks like a mistake, and stop only needs relaxed. I'm pretty sure I've done that on weakly ordered platforms and it works fine. I'd like an expert to confirm this too.

Comment: How about _"...and an atomic load in thread B from the same variable is tagged memory_order_acquire, __all memory writes__ (non-atomic and __relaxed atomic__) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B. ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order  ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Can you elaborate? That doesn't happen in this case, since nobody performs an acquire (and `stop = true;` performs a seq-cst release, or no release at all if the relaxed order is used), but it's not a problem, since workers will see the updated value sooner or later anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `mo_relaxed` is fine for both load and store of a `stop` flag

There's also **no meaningful latency benefit** to stronger memory orders, even if latency of seeing a change to a `keep_running` or `exit_now` flag was important.

IDK why Herb thinks `stop.store` shouldn't be relaxed; in his talk, his slides have a comment that says `// not relaxed` on the assignment, but he doesn't say anything about the store side before moving on to "is it worth it".

Of course, the load runs inside the worker loop, but the store runs only once, and Herb really likes to recommend sticking with SC unless you have a performance reason that truly justifies using something else.  I hope that wasn't his only reason; I find that unhelpful when trying to understand what memory order would actually be necessary and why.  But anyway, I think either that or a mistake on his part.

---

**The ISO C++ standard** doesn't say anything about how soon stores become visible or what might influence that.  These apply to all atomic operations, including `relaxed`.  They're not just notes, but only *should* not *must*.

ISO C++ section *6.9.2.3 Forward progress*

> [18.](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#18) An implementation should ensure that the last value (in modification order) assigned by an atomic or synchronization operation will become visible to all other threads **in a finite period of time.**

And *33.5.4 Order and consistency [atomics.order]* covering only atomics, not mutexes etc.:

> [11.](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#11) Implementations should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads **within a reasonable amount of time.**

Inter-thread latency is primarily a quality-of-implementation thing, with the standard leaving things wide open.  Normal C++ implementations that work by compiling to asm for some architecture effectively just expose the hardware's cache-coherence properties, so typically tens of nanoseconds best case, sub-microsecond near-worst case if both threads are currently running on different cores.  (Otherwise scheduler timeslice...)

---

Another thread can loop arbitrarily many times before its load actually sees this store value, even if they're both `seq_cst`, assuming there's no other synchronization of any kind between them.  Low inter-thread latency is a performance issue, not correctness / formal guarantee.

And non-infinite inter-thread latency is apparently only a "should" QOI (quality of implementation) issue. :P  Nothing in the standard suggests that `seq_cst` would help on a hypothetical implementation where store visibility could be delayed indefinitely, although one might guess that could be the case, e.g. on a hypothetical implementation with explicit cache flushes instead of cache coherency.  (Although [such an implementation is probably not practically usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118) in terms of performance with CPUs anything like what we have now; every release and/or acquire operation would have to flush the whole cache.)

**On real hardware** (which uses some form of MESI cache coherency), different memory orders for store or load don't make stores visible sooner in real time, they just control whether later operations can become globally visible while still waiting for the store to commit from the store buffer to L1d cache.  (After invalidating any other copies of the line.)

**Stronger orders, and barriers, don't make things happen sooner in an absolute sense, they just delay other things until they're allowed to happen relative to the store or load.**  (This is the case on all real-world CPUs AFAIK; they always try to make stores visible to other cores ASAP anyway, so the store buffer doesn't fill up.)

See also (my similar answers on):

- [Does hardware memory barrier make visibility of atomic operations faster in addition to providing necessary guarantees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591287/does-hardware-memory-barrier-make-visibility-of-atomic-operations-faster-in-addi)
- [If I don't use fences, how long could it take a core to see another core's writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292687/if-i-dont-use-fences-how-long-could-it-take-a-core-to-see-another-cores-write)
- [memory_order_relaxed and visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66054666/memory-order-relaxed-and-visibility/66128464#66128464)
- [Thread synchronization: How to guarantee visibility of writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009411/thread-synchronization-how-to-guarantee-visibility-of-writes) (it's a non-issue on current real hardware)

The second Q&A is about x86 where commit from the store buffer to L1d cache is in program order. That limits how far past a cache-miss store execution can get, and also any possible benefit of putting a release or seq_cst fence after the store to prevent later stores (and loads) from maybe competing for resources.  (x86 microarchitectures will do RFO (read for ownership) before stores reach the head of the store buffer, and plain loads normally compete for resources to track RFOs we're waiting for a response to.)  But these effects are extremely minor in terms of something like exiting another thread; only very small scale reordering.

---

> because who cares if the thread stops with a slightly bigger delay.

More like, who cares if the thread gets more work done by **not making loads/stores after the load wait for the check to complete**.  (Of course, this work will get discarded if it's in the shadow of a a mis-speculated branch on the load result when we eventually load `true`.)  The cost of rolling back to a consistent state after a branch mispredict is more or less independent of how much already-executed work had happened beyond the mispredicted branch.  And it's a `stop` flag which presumably doesn't get set very often, so the total amount of wasted work costing cache/memory bandwidth for other CPUs is pretty minimal.

That phrasing makes it sound like an `acquire` load or `release` store would actually get the the store seen sooner in absolute real time, rather than just relative to other code in this thread.  (Which is not the case).

The benefit is more instruction-level and memory-level parallelism across loop iterations when the load produces a `false`.  And simply avoiding running extra instructions on ISAs where an acquire or especially an SC load needs extra instructions, especially expensive 2-way barrier instructions (like PowerPC `isync`/`sync` or especially ARMv7 `dmb ish` full barrier even for acquire), not like ARMv8 `ldapr` or x86 `mov` acquire-load instructions.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KxTsEhG3x))

---

BTW, Herb is right that **the `dirty` flag** can also be `relaxed`, but only because of the `thread.join` sync between the reader and any possible writer.  Otherwise yeah, release / acquire.

But in this case, `dirty` only needs to be `atomic<>` at all because of possible simultaneous writers all storing the same value, which ISO C++ still deems data-race UB. e.g. because of the theoretical possibility of hardware race-detection that traps on conflicting non-atomic accesses.  (Or a software implementations like `clang -fsanitize=thread`)

---

Fun fact: C++20 introduced [`std::stop_token`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token) for use as a `stop` or `keep_running` flag.

Comment: Related: [MESI Protocol & std::atomic - Does it ensure all writes are immediately visible to other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60292095)  / my comments on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67330#issuecomment-1083539281 and also  [Is a memory barrier required to read a value that is atomically modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71722126)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `stop.store(true, mo_relaxed)` would be enough in this context.

```
launch_workers()
stop = true;  // not relaxed
join_workers()';
```

> why does `stop = true;` in the main thread use seq_cst?

Herb does not mention the reason why he uses `mo_seq_cst`, but let's look at a few possibilities.

- Based on the "`not relaxed`" comment, he is worried that `stop.store(true, mo_relaxed)` can be re-ordered with `launch_workers()` or `join_workers()`.
  Since `launch_workers()` is a release operation and `join_workers()` is an acquire operation, the ordering constraints for both will not prevent the store to move in either direction.
  However, it is important to notice that for this scenario, it does not really matter whether the store to `stop` uses `mo_relaxed` or `mo_seq_cst`.
  Even with the strongest ordering, `mo_seq_cst` (which by the absence of other SC operations is no stronger than `mo_release`), the ordering rules still allow the re-ordering with `join_workers()`.
  Of course this reordering isn't going to happen, but my point is that stronger ordering contraints on the store isn't going to make a difference.
- He could make the argument that a sequentially consistent (SC) store is an advantage since the thread performing the relaxed load will pick up on the new value sooner
  (an SC store flushes the store buffer).
  But this seems hardly relevant because the store is in between creating and joining threads, which is not in a tight loop, or as Herb puts it:
  "*..is it in a performance-critical region of code where this overhead matters?..*"
  He also says about the load: "*..you don't care when it arrives..*"

We don't know the real reason, but it is possibly based on the programming convention that you don't use explicit ordering parameters (which means `mo_seq_cst`), unless it makes a difference,
and in this case, as Herb explains, only the relaxed load makes a difference.

For example, on the weakly ordered PowerPC platform, a `load(mo_seq_cst)` uses both the (expensive) `sync` and (less expensive) `isync` instructions,
a `load(mo_acquire)` still uses `isync` and a `load(mo_relaxed)` uses none of them. In a tight loop, that is a good optimization.
Also worth mentioning is that on the mainstream `X86`platform, there is no real difference in performance between `load(mo_seq_cst)` and `load(mo_relaxed)`

Personally I favor this programming style where ordering parameters are omitted when they don't matter and used when they make a difference.

```
stop.store(true); // ordering irrelevant, but uses SC
stop.store(true, memory_order_seq_cst); // store requires SC ordering (which is rare)
```

It's only a matter of style.. for both stores, the compiler will generate the same assembly.

Comment: That's an interesting observation - formally, it seems the code is wrong even with `seq_cst`, as the compiler could move `stop = true` after the join, which would be catastrophic.  And under the literal language of the standard, I don't see how it can be fixed.  If `join()` were really an acquire operation, putting a `seq_cst` fence between `stop=true` and the join would fix it - but `join` is not an "atomic operation" so it does not participate in the seq_cst ordering.

Comment: @NateEldredge I did not really want to make the statement that it is wrong, only that existing the ordering rules might allow it.
But there are other rules that will prevent it from happening because it is (nearly) impossible that the store can be executed after the join, I'm just not sure which rules.
Jeff Preshing has written about a [similar case](https://preshing.com/20170612/can-reordering-of-release-acquire-operations-introduce-deadlock)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking some more and came to the same conclusion.  Since any store, even a relaxed one, should become visible in finite time, the compiler cannot reorder it past the join which may potentially take forever.  There is the "should" which I guess makes it QoI, but even if they had said "must", a DeathStation 9000 could say "fine, stores become visible after 5000 years" and we'd be no better off.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yup, exactly. Compile-time reordering that creates a deadlock would violate the finite-time requirement (suggestion?) in the standard.    [How C++ Standard prevents deadlock in spinlock mutex with memory\_order\_acquire and memory\_order\_release?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61299704) - runtime reordering is allowed, but compile-time reordering that nails that down into the only possible ordering would not be following the as-if rule.  Of course some practical considerations make this reordering completely impossible in practice, like `.join` involving a non-inline call.